# Skip building jar in Gradle groovy scripts project

Tags: gradle, groovy

I have a gradle groovy project where I only have groovy scripts that are not in a source dir, but a separate dir. Additionally I have groovy junit tests that test the scripts invoking them using groovy shell.

I have a gradle build that runs the tests, then zips the scripts into separate zip files and uploads them into maven repo. The problem is, that gradle also creates and uploads a jar file. Since there are no files in source dirs, the jar contains only a generated manifest file.

In reality I don't need the jar at all.Is it possible to configure gradle to not create a jar file for a groovy project?

I upload the artifacts using uploadArchives task.

My full gradle config:

```
group 'groupName'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

apply plugin: 'groovy'
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'maven'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.3.11'
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
}

task scriptsZip(type: Zip) {
    from 'scripts'
}

artifacts {
    archives file: scriptsZip.archivePath, type: 'zip', classifier: 'scripts', builtBy: scriptsZip
}

uploadArchives {
    repositories {
        mavenDeployer {
            repository(url: "file://C:\\testRepo")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify the `jar` task with an `onlyIf` condition, to skip building the jar when some condition is met (or not met)

```
jar {
   onlyIf { /*some condition*/ }
}
```

In your case, it might make sense to check if there are any source files in your main sourceset:

```
jar {
   onlyIf { !sourceSets.main.allSource.files.isEmpty() }
}
```

Comment: Now i'm getting an error: "Execution failed for task ':uploadArchives'." because the jar doesn't exist.

Comment: are you using uploadArchives to publish your zip? Can you show your uploadArchives config?

Comment: uploadArchives {
    repositories {
        mavenDeployer {
            repository(url: "file://C:\\testRepo")
        }
    }
}

Comment: please add this information to your question. Also, how do you build your zip?

Comment: It turned out that the maven-publish plugin works better than maven plugin and you can define to have only zip artifacts.

Comment: That is true. Maven-publish is newer and more configurable. Is your issue resolved now?

Comment: yes, my issue is resolved by switching to maven-publish plugin

Comment: I have 10 projects in which 1 project has the jars which has to be taken from local filesystem. my intention was to skip the project if the required dependendencies are not available on trying this solution my build is failing for the remaining 9 projects. @RaGe can you suggest the optimal way of doing it ?